# Java Spring Rest não funciona com pacotes separados

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Pessoal minha aplicação spring rest so funciona quando coloco as classes(models,controllers) tudo no mesmo pacote da classe application, dessa forma funciona mas imagine a desorganização disso !!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYIav.png

*Dessa forma não funciona, o servidor sobe para a porta 8080 porem não retorna meu metodo, apenas se eu colocar o controller dentro do pacote da application

#### CONTROLLER

```
package com.camila.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ClienteController {
    @GetMapping("/clientes")
    public String listar() {
        return "TESTE ";
     }
}
```

#### APPLICATION

```
package com.camila.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### POM.XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.camila.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_API</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring_API</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, o site ja me ajudou muito pra resolver outros problemas mas nunca de fato fiz pergunta aqui

Comment: só esta com um comando pra trocar a porta "server.port = 8090"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação do Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class) a anotação `@SpringBootApplication`, entre outras coisas, define a raíz da aplicação. Isso é, por convenção a classe anotada com `@SpringBootApplication` deve estar no pacote mais externo da hierarquia de classes da sua aplicação.

Na prática a anotação `@SpringBootApplication` "marca" o pacote da aplicação (bem como todos os pacotes dentro desse pacote) para ser escaneado em busca de componentes anotados do Spring.

Pesando que sua classe `SpringApiApplication` esteja no pacote `com.camila.web` o Spring Boot consegue encontrar componentes dentro de qualquer subpacote de `com.camila.web`, por exemplo:

- `com.camila.web`
- `com.camila.web.controller`
- `com.camila.web.meupacote.meuoutropacote`

Como `ClienteController` não está dentro do pacote `com.camila.web` o Spring Boot não sabe como encontrá-lo.

Uma solução para o seu problema, que respeita a convenção do Spring Boot sem fazer uma bagunça, é mover o pacote `controller` para dentro de `com.camila.web`.

```
package com.camila.web.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ClienteController {
    @GetMapping("/clientes")
    public String listar() {
        return "TESTE ";
     }
}
```

Note que você pode organizar seus componentes como e em quantos pacotes quiser sem desrespeitar a convenção do Spring Boot, desde que todos os pacotes estejam dentro de `com.camila.web`.

Caso você realmente precise usar componentes em outros pacotes, a anotação [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) possui elementos opcionais `scanBasePackages` e `scanBasePackageClasses` utilizados para fazer o Spring Boot buscar componentes em outros pacotes. Por exemplo, considerando a sua estrutura de pacotes atual você poderia  modificar a classe `SpringApiApplication` da seguinte maneira:

```
package com.camila.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.camila.controller", "meu.outro.pacote"})
public class SpringApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Com isso a sua classe `ClienteController`, bem como quaisquer outros componentes nos pacotes `com.camila.controller` e `meu.outro.pacote` são encontrados pelo Spring.

Lendo o [código da classe SpringBootApplication](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java) fica claro que toda essa "mágica" acontece pois a anotação `@SpringBootApplication` é por sua vez anotadada com a anotação [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) (esse é um exemplo de meta anotação). Por consequência a anotação `@ComponentScan` também pode ser utilizada diretamente para obter o mesmo resultado:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.camila.controller", "meu.outro.pacote"})
```

Dito isso, é recomendável seguir as convenções do Spring para evitar ter que fazer configurações manuais desnecessárias. Por exemplo, caso você venha a trabalhar com JPA o Spring Boot detecta automaticamente entidades e repositórios dentro do seu pacote raíz. Se suas entidades não estiverem dentro do pacote raíz será necessário usar `@EntityScan` para indicar para o Spring onde encontrar suas entidades e `@EnableJpaRepositories` para indicar onde encontrar os repositórios.
Esse princípio é chamado [Convenção sobre configuração](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o_sobre_configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e é especialmente válido em *opinionated frameworks* como Spring Boot.

Comment: Anthony muito obrigado mesmo pelo tempo, a informação por sí ajuda muita. Porem olha que estranho, quando clico em cima do com.camila.web e peço para criar outro pacote, que seria um subpacote do mesmo, ele cria um dentro de com.camila.web como planejado e um fora como se fosse um espelho, bom testando novamente ainda não funciona , será que estou criando sub pacote da forma errada, segue imagem

Comment: Consegui !! Ficou dessa forma que eu expliquei meio que "espelhando" e depois de alguns reboots deu certo (vai entender ne rs), muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

Só colocar a sua classe "SpringApiApplication" na pasta src/main/java, a classe application tem que ter a mesma hierarquia das pastas, assim ela consegue enxergar as pastas, se ela estiver dentro de alguma pasta ela só irá enxergar o que esta no nivel de hierarquia dela.